# SQL Server Management Studio Results Scrolling

Tags: ssms

I find myself doing a lot of scrolling through thru hundreds of results within the SSMS which is pretty painful.  Does anyone know a faster way to scroll through a large number of Results in SSMS?  Page down doesn't seem to be supported.  Even if there was an option to go to a specific row within the results would be a big help.

Comment: Can you please define "large number of results" ? millions? a couple of millions? If that is the case, SSMS may not be the right way of viewing such number of records

Comment: I agree with @OzanGunceler: If you're scrolling through a large amount of results in SSMS, trying to find a specific row, I think you'd be better off revising your query (as in his answer). You can also save your results to a CSV file, and then open it up in Excel.

Comment: This is typically less than 50K records.  Definitely agree on changing the query however, in this case it's an debug/error log so for troubleshooting reasons you need to see the records as they are recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly achievable through SSMS interface but you can try something like the following.

First, determine which row number you'd like to jump to (index starts at one) and execute your query with the OFFSET and FETCH NEXT statements

```
SELECT * FROM Expense ORDER BY Id ASC OFFSET  4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

OFFSET means how many rows you'd like to skip from the top, FETCH NEXT determines how many rows to display after the offset.

You can select the first row after skipping 20 rows (in other words, obtaining row 21), do the following

```
SELECT * FROM Expense ORDER BY Id ASC OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Not the best way of doing it, did not consider performance of such approach. But the easiest to achieve what you are looking for.

Another way could be executing the full query in Excel and use Ctrl + G to go to specific row number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct option for easy scrolling. You need to filter the result or export/copy the result to excel.
Usually I will copy the result to excel. This will give a clean look and also we can filter the result if needed in excel. :)